# split Screen into two part (with Effect)

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

i Have Browser Control in my form that fill all screen

```
        WebBrowser objBowser = new WebBrowser();
        objBowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.Controls.Add(objBowser);
        objBowser.Navigate("http://www.google.com/");
```

and have one button for split screen into two part for two browser control

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            WebBrowser objBowser = new WebBrowser();
            objBowser.Width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width ;
            objBowser.Dock = DockStyle.Left;
            this.Controls.Add(objBowser);
            objBowser.Navigate("http://www.google.com/");
        }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        WebBrowser objBowser2 = new WebBrowser();

        objBowser2.Dock = DockStyle.Right;
        this.Controls.Add(objBowser2);
        objBowser2.Navigate("http://www.google.com/");
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        while ( objBowser2.Width <= Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width / 2)
        {
            objBowser2.Width += 1;
            objBowser1.Width -= 1;
        }
    }
```

i have used timer with `1` as interval and `objBowser2.Width += 1` technique for animation for split but it doesnt seems good , any idea ?

Comment: I don't get your purpose well, you want to have 2 `WebBrowser` controls on your form (which is maximized?) and the 2 controls should have the same `Width` (so each one has the width of approximate screen width / 2)? You need some kind of animation to collapse this and expand the other using a `Timer`?

Comment: as default i have one webbrowser that is maximized , when button clicked ,second browser show in right , and first one dock in other side . this operation done with effect , what is the best way to do ?

Comment: @Moslem7026 What seems to be the problem you're getting with your code?

Comment: timer doesnt have good effect and is not light wight , i want to do by alternative way , like wpf !

Comment: This isn't your real code.  objBowser1 isn't declared, objBowser and objBowser were declared as local objects, so they aren't in scope for the timer_tick event, which you never start the timer anyway.  Try using a SplitContainer.  The AnimateWindow api can do some useful animations, but if you are looking to duplicate the abilities of WPF, then just use WPF.